# Running rake tasks to start Resque workers on Heroku

Tags: heroku, rake, backgroundworker, redis, resque

So I have Resque and redis to go set up on Heroku and this is what my `resque.rake` file looks like:

```
require 'resque/tasks'

task "resque:setup" => :environment do
  ENV['QUEUE'] = '*'
end

desc "Alias for resque:work (To run workers on Heroku)"
task "jobs:work" => "resque:work"
```

I ran `heroku rake jobs:work` and got one worker running. This worked perfectly. My background jobs were being completed.

Then I made some changes in my code, pushed to heroku, and still saw that I had one worker running. However, while jobs were being added to the queue, the worker was not receiving any jobs. So I ran `heroku rake jobs:work` again, it said I had two workers running, and my jobs were being completed.

My question is why did this happen? Do I need to run this rake task every time I push to heroku? Is there a way to automate this? Also, although I have two workers running, there seems to be only one that is working. Is there a way to get back to one worker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Procfile for resque jobs on heroku http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

Keep in mind that Procfile is used on new Heroku Cedar Stack.

Answer (score -1):

You only need one worker for Resque. You will need to run `heroku rake jobs:work` or use [Resque-Scheduler](https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler) (cron, or something to run that task) to to automatically run your jobs.

Comment: While this might be true, this doesn't answer my question